# How to use the 'numbered list' formatting option correctly?

Tags: support

If I highlight a series of new sentences (not code) and click on the Numbered List icon, all but the first sentence is erased.
If I manually type the sequential numbers for additional sentences, the formatted display shows those sentences as additionally indented under the first.
What is the correct way to format two or three paragraphs as an indented numbered list?

Answer (score 3):

I took a risk of hitting submit on an answer and discovered

1. If I type a CarriageReturn, then type the number (and dot) followed by a sentence...
2. And then manually type another number, dot, and sentence
3. Despite what the "preview" shows, the final output will be formatted as a numbered list.

Sorry if the questions sounded dumb. The "preview" was throwing me off.